# Can´t recognize rxjs 7 on angular project

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs7

In my service.ts

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Expense } from '../models/expense';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExpenseService {


   private getUrl: string = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/expenses";

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getExpenses(): Observable<Expense[]> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Expense[]>(this.getUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response)
    )
  }

}
```

And in my package.json i got this

```
 "name": "expensetrackerfrontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

I have already tried other forms to import rxjs but the error its always the same.
I don´t know if the problem its because I´m using a new version of angular cli
I hope can anyone help me

[image]

Comment: what's the typescript version in your package.json file?

Comment: typescript": "~4.5.2"

Comment: thanks, i discovered this issue, but the resolution is about having 4.2 or more: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6350

Comment: but i can use rxjs/operats and this dont make any sense, for what version should i update my typescript ?

Comment: I encourage you to try to delete node_modules and reinstall them as a try. If it doesn't work, please open an issue on rxjs repository here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.yml